# What cache strategy do I need in this case ?

Tags: asp.net, caching, .net-4.0

I have what I consider to be a fairly simple application. A service returns some data based on another piece of data. A simple example, given a state name, the service returns the capital city.

All the data resides in a SQL Server 2008 database. The majority of this "static" data will rarely change. It will occassionally need to be updated and, when it does, I have no problem restarting the application to refresh the cache, if implemented.

Some data, which is more "dynamic", will be kept in the same database. This data includes contacts, statistics, etc. and will change more frequently (anywhere from hourly to daily to weekly). This data will be linked to the static data above via foreign keys (just like a SQL JOIN).

My question is, what exactly am I trying to implement here ? and how do I get started doing it ? I know the static data will be cached but I don't know where to start with that. I tried searching but came up with so much stuff and I'm not sure where to start. Recommendations for tutorials would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to cache anything until you have a performance problem.  Until you have a noticeable problem and have measured your application tiers to determine your database is in fact a bottleneck, which it rarely is, then start looking into caching data.  It is always a tradeoff, memory vs CPU vs real time data availability.  There is no reason to make your application more complicated than it needs to be just because.

Answer (score 0):

An extremely simple 'win' here (I assume you're using WCF here) would be to use the declarative attribute-based caching mechanism built into the framework. It's easy to set up and manage, but you need to analyze your usage scenarios to make sure it's applied at the right locations to really benefit from it. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443.aspx) article is a good starting point.

Beyond that, I'd recommend looking into one of the many WCF books that deal with higher-level concepts like caching and try to figure out if their implementation patterns are applicable to your design.